# The pivot name is not getting assigned,how to debug?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have created a macro to create a pivot for the data present in a sheet named **"data"**. I put in the name of the pivot as **"Pivot_Data"** but when the pivot gets created the name comes as sheet1 for the pivot sheet, I was expecting **"Pivot_Data"**?

Also can any help in debugging the pivot cache as well? I mean how data gets *cached* in pivot cache in addition to any watch in the macro to see who and what is going in pivot cache?

Any help would be appreciated.

**My code:**

```
'To set up my workbook & worksheet variables.
Dim bReport As Workbook, Report As Worksheet, pivotSheet As Worksheet     
Set bReport = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set Report = bReport.Worksheets("data") 'Create the worksheet to place the SQL data
Set pivotSheet = bReport.Worksheets.Add 'Create the worksheet to place the Pivot Table

Dim pivotSource As Range 'To set up the variable representing your pivot data.
Set pivotSource = Report.UsedRange 'selecting entire data in the sheet

Dim tableName As String
tableName = "Pivot_Data"  'name of pivot report i wanted to create from data in sheet Prod

bReport.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pivotSource).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), tableName:=tableName

Set pt = pivotSheet.PivotTables(tableName)
pivotSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1)
Set pOne= pt.PivotFields("Number")
Set pTwo = pt.PivotFields("Premium")
Set pthree = pt.PivotFields("TransactoinID")
Set pFour = pt.PivotFields("money")

pOne.Orientation = xlRowField 'This assigns the orientation of a given field to xlRowField.
pTwo.Orientation = xlRowField
pTwo.Subtotals(1) = False 'This denotes there will be no subtotal for this field.
pThree.Orientation = xlRowField
pThree.Subtotals(1) = False
pFour.Orientation = xlDataField
pFour.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Comment: I have no issues with you code above does it fail somewhere? Did you want the sheet to be re-named? If that is the case add this to your code after the `.add` statement `pivotSheet.Name = "Pivot_Data"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to name the sheet you need to add another line of code to rename it:

```
Set pivotSource = Report.UsedRange 

Dim tableName As String
tableName = "Pivot_Data"
pivotSheet.Name = tableName '<~~ new line to change sheet name
```